# Is replace after < sign on echo but var_dump shows the correct length

Tags: php, string, php-5.6

I have to generate a string using a given word, let's say "wheel" for full-text boolean mode search. But the second appearance of that word is replace after "<" sign when I'm trying to set the priority:

```
$word = 'wheel';
$x = '+(>' . $word . ' <' . $word . '*)';
echo $x;
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
+(>wheel <wheel*)
```

But instead the result is looking like this:

```
+(>wheel
```

But when I'm using `var_dump` I get the right length which is `17`

I'm using PHP `5.6.40`
Any idea why?

Comment: works fine PHP 7.2. What version PHP are you using?

Comment: @suspectus, i've updated the question now, it's php 5.6.40

Comment: Your code works, if you don't see `<wheel` it is probably because you display the result in your browser that see it like an opening tag. Display the page code source (right click: code source) to see it.

Comment: Have you tried `$x = '+(>' . $word . ' <(' . $word . '*))';` ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte wow...i didn't even think about it, even for 1 second! you are right! :O thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it's happening but if you add a space after  < and single comma it's working fine. like this

```
$word = 'wheel';
$x = '+(>' . $word . ' < ' . $word . '*)';
echo $x;
```

Note: The extra space between `< Symbol` and `' Symbol`

Comment: you didn't read the question @BlackXero, i need the < operator for full-text search, adding an extra space removes its purpose